# Show dynamic counter in TYPO3 6.2 backend module name

Tags: module, backend, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

For an extended comment-adminstration I'd like to create a backend module.
To show if there are any new comments that need the administrators attention, a counter of unresolved issues in the module name would be great.
The output should look like:

> Comments awaiting moderation (42)

Is this even possible in TYPO3, or should I look for another way to remind the moderators about them? Until now it's e-mail notifications, but after we received nearly 15000 comments so far, another solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use sys_news to show a message on the login page.

Comment: To be honest, I've had to google this because I have never made contact with the system messages in TYPO3 until now.
It's not a perfect solution, but far betten than the e-mails. Thank you :)
I'm still open for other solutions though